# How can I access response.context when testing a Jinja2 powered Django view

Tags: django, testing, jinja2, django-testing

When I use the Django test.client and I do something like:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_this(self):
        c = self.client
        response = c.get('/')
        assert False, response.context['name']
```

I get an error:

```
assert False, response.context['name']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

My only guess is something with using Jinja2 is preventing the context from showing up when I test.

Note this test is intentionally rigged to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I've been meaning to readup on `TestCase`. After perusing the docs it looks you might have an error. Assertions are methods of the `TestCase` class.

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
  def test_this(self):
    response=self.client.get('/')
    self.assertEquals(response.context['name'],'Jim')
```

Comment: Thanks for the typo catch, I meant

   assert False, response.context['name'] 

I want the test to fail, because I want to see what's in response.context['name']

Comment: I would think this test would fail unless 'Jim' is `response.context['name']`

Answer (score 1):

Django's *monkey patches* the `Template` class overriding the `render` method to be able to send the `template_rendered` signal and populate `response.context`.

If you dig the code you will be able to do this for Jinja2's Template class.

Answer (score 1):

I've done what @Rho has suggested this way (in the beginning of the page load tests file)

```
from jinja2 import Template as Jinja2Template
from django.test import signals

#note - this code can be run only once
ORIGINAL_JINJA2_RENDERER = Jinja2Template.render
def instrumented_render(template_object, *args, **kwargs):
    context = dict(*args, **kwargs)
    signals.template_rendered.send(
                            sender=template_object,
                            template=template_object,
                            context=context
                        )
    return ORIGINAL_JINJA2_RENDERER(template_object, *args, **kwargs)
Jinja2Template.render = instrumented_render
```

Then you can pick out the response context and template name (however response.template is not a list in this case) and instead of `response.template[0].name` you'll need to use `response.template.name`.

Comment: That did it! Only change: "from jinja2.template import Template" should be changed to "from jinja2 import Template". Thanks @Evgeny!

Answer (score 1):

Jinja sets context_data variable, not context:

```
response = client.get('/')
print response.context_data
```